# Clojure Match - no method in multimethod 'to-source'

Tags: clojure, pattern-matching

Attempting to use clojure match like so:

```
(defn eval-arraklisp
  "not sure yet"
  [tree scope]
  (match tree
         [:SYM sym] (lookup sym scope)
         [:NUM num] (read-string num)
         [:FUN & params body] [:FUN & body]
         [:CALL [:SYM sym] & args] (call-sym sym scope args)
         [:CALL [:FUN & params body] & args]))
```

I get the following on the `(match tree` line:

```
#error {
 :cause No method in multimethod 'to-source' for dispatch value:  :clojure.core.match/rest
 :via
 [{:type clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException
```

Can't figure out why.

Comment: A guess: You can't have `[:FUN & body]` as a return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in following line:

```
     [:FUN & params body] [:FUN & body]
```

There are two symbols in rest section of match, in particular `params` and `body`, but it is not allowed to have more than one. This causes error you are getting.

Probably, you should rewrite this match clause as follows:

```
     [:FUN params & body] [:FUN & body]
```

Also, as noted by @Andre, you should review the return value of this match, because `&` symbol is definitely redundant there.